# Nopcommerce "New" Product indicator

Tags: nopcommerce

I'm new to NopCommerce, I've got an issue I want to be able to have an indicator to display on the `ProductTemplate.Simple.cshtml` to display a product is new. So I'm trying to figure out the best approach, or if there currently is a service on NopCommerce that already provides the solution.

I'm currently stuck on finding a solution for this issue? Does anyone know where to start looking? Or has come across the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

From description of the question, I assume that you want to indicate product is new on detail page, for that you've to modify the code.

Add one new field in   Nop.Web > Models > Catalog `ProductDetailsModel`

```
public partial class ProductDetailsModel : BaseNopEntityModel
{
    ...

    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
}
```

Assign value of it from Nop.Web > Factories > `ProductModelFactory`

```
public virtual ProductDetailsModel PrepareProductDetailsModel(Product product, ShoppingCartItem updatecartitem = null, bool isAssociatedProduct = false) 
{
    var model = new ProductDetailsModel {
    ...
    ...
    IsNew = product.MarkAsNew
    };
}
```

Add condition to display it on view page:

```
<div class="product-name">
  <h1 itemprop="name">
      @Model.Name
      @if (Model.IsNew)
      {
          <b>(This is a new product)</b>
          //TODO: add your code here
      }
  </h1>
</div>
```

---

To check if it is working or not, mark product as new from admin end (I have used *Apple iCam* here)

[image]

---

Go and refresh the detail page:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find ribbon plugin over the marketplace of the nopcommerce or you can develop it by yourself. Otherwise You can show a new sticker at presentation==>nop.web==>themes==>your theme==>Shared==>_ProductBox.cshtml depending on the "MarkAsNew" property of the "ProductOverviewModel"